# Passing object available in the template into the {{render}} helper doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an object defined globally as `App.configObj` which contains a property `data`. Inside a view's template I can use `{{App.configObj.data}}` to display the value and it works fine.

Inside that same template, I use `{{render "viewC" model config=App.configObj}`} to render a similar view, but the `config` property on that view remains null on `didInsertElement`. Other arguments set to primitive values are correctly set at that point.

Since App.configObj is definitely available in that context, shouldn't I be able to pass it into that view?

Here is the jsbin that illustrates the situation: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/misiyaki/12/edit

If you comment out the render call for `ViewC`, you can see that `{{App.configObj.data}}` renders just fine in the template.

My goal is to use an object encapsulating several properties to configure the view, so I need to be able to pass that object in. I spent a lot of time searching for similar content online but didn't find anyone trying this.

**What am I missing?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I understand your struggle here with not being able to pass in a property in your render code... but in this case it doesn't seem that that is truly necessary.

Here is a fiddle with some changes to show you another way, that is essentially the same thing if i understood your intentions correctly.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/misiyaki/15/edit

The new code for your view:

```
App.ViewCView = Em.View.extend({
  name: 'testName',
  config: function () {
    return App.configObj;
  }.property(),
  data: function () {
    return this.get('config.data')
  }.property('config'),
  templateName: 'view-c'
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue is that this view must be configurable with different objects. In one instance, I might render it with config A and in a different instance I want to configure it with a B. So it seemed appropriate to pass in the config object to use with the render helper. If I add it to ViewC's code, then it is no longer configurable. 

My use case is a view that implements a grid. The config object contains column configurations, so in each render a different set of columns might be passed in.

Would there be another way to externally provide a config object to that view?